# JQuery Mobile 1.4.0 - Hosting the files... CSS not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Trying to give 1.4 a go however it just will not do anything CSS based for me. In earlier versions this gave me a nice toolbar at the top of my page with 'data-role="header", but now - nothing. The following code works fine pre-1.4 but not after. All files are hosted in the same folder as my index.html.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>App Name</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css"/>
        <script src="jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<!-- Main Page -->
    <section>
        <div data-role="page" id="main_page" data-theme="a">
            <div data-role="header" id="header" data-theme="a">
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Has something changed /am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: You are missing a `</section>` and a `</div>` close tags. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: is `js` present in same folder as your `html`???

Comment: I realised I was missing </section> and </div>, that was down to poor copy and pasting but still have the same issue. The .js is in the same folder as my index.html

Answer (score 0):

Check the files on your file system, maybe the filenames that you entered on your HTML file was wrong or use CDN instead of hosting it on your own. CDN is better than hosting it on your own
For CDN use this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>App Name</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.1/jquery.mobile-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Main Page -->
    <section>
    <div data-role="page" id="main_page" data-theme="a">
      <div data-role="header" id="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Header</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```